# Access Gunicorn worker from django request

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

From a Django request, how do I access the Gunicorn worker that is running that request?

Comment: What do you mean, "access" the worker? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: access a property that I previously set on it in:

    `post_worker_init(worker)`